# tiny-dnnで学習,生成したjson形式のネットワークファイルをUnityで使いたい

Tags: 深層学習, unity2d

tiny-dnn(C++)で学習、生成したjson形式のネットワークファイルがあるのですが、これをUnity(C#)で使いたいです。
どのような方法があるでしょうか？
なるべく無償の範囲でできると嬉しいです。
tiny-dnnのネットワークファイルをそのまま使えるのが理想ですが、
必要ならばなにがしかの変換をかけてUnityで使えるようにするなども選択肢としてありです。

Comment: UnityにBarracudaというライブラリがあるようで、調べ始めました。

Comment: onnx という共通フォーマット？がありBarracudaはonnxをサポートしてるらしい。でもtiny-dnnはonnxサポートしてないっぽい？

Comment: tiny-dnnはcaffeからインポートは出来るけどエクスポートはできないみたい。

Comment: 厳しい。教師データはあるのでtiny-dnn捨ててほかのライブラリで学習し直しが現実的か？

Comment: pytorchで学習しなおしてonnx形式で吐き出してbarracudaで使うという線を考え中

Comment: swigを使えばpytorchで学習する際にC++のコードが流用できる。

Comment: pytorchで学習できました。次はonnx形式でエクスポートしてBarracudaで読み込みです。

Comment: pytorchで学習し、onnx形式でエクスポートしたファイルをBarracudaで使えました。これにて完了です。